# Will XCode break if I change AppleID?

Tags: xcode, apple-id, developer-program

For the past year I have had my old appleid that I used with my own personal IOS developer portal account at Apple. Recently I joined a new company and want to get onto their developer program. When I joined the company, I received a new Mac and I used my old AppleID to install XCode. In other words, now my Mac only knows about my old AppledID.

Since I now want to join my new company's IOS developer account at Apple, I have two choices: either continue to use my old AppleID (still associated with my personal IOS dev acctount) or create a new AppleID (using my new work email).

If I use my old AppleID, how does Apple know which dev account I want when I log in? Will this cause problems?

Or if I create and use a new AppleID, will XCode stop working for me (since it was downloaded using the old AppleID)? What would I have to do to fix the problem? Which route is easier?

Answer (score 2):

You can log in to iTunes with multiple Apple ID accounts. In my case I have a personal account and a work account with dev access.

Once the xcode (or any app) is installed it doesn't case who's Apple ID is logged in, however you may have to do some bouncing between accounts if you have installed apps from both accounts and you need to update them. other then that two accounts works fine.